# How to utilize same user to proceed further actions after login in jmeter

Tags: authentication, installation, jmeter

If 10 users are supposed to explore xyz pages after login, how do we make sure that 10 users will login only at once and proceed the other actions of exploring xyz pages multiple times in jmeter.
How can we utilize setup threadgroup here?

Answer (score 0):

Using setUp Thread Group is an overkill, you have i.e. [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) in order to perform login only during first iteration.

Just make sure you have `Clear cookies each iteration` box **unchecked** for the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) and the same for `Clear cache each iteration` for the [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)